# What is the definition of a hairline?

Tags: typography

Is it the thin strokes in a letter like "O"?
[image]

Or is it the thin strokes in a letter like "M"?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Hairline" generally refers to a stroke or line smaller then 0.25pt in width. Sometimes it may mean smaller than 0.5pt in width.

"Hairline" is not *directly* associated with any type glyph and is not a term used exclusively for typography. A Hairline can be any line, any where.

Comment: My understanding (and it may be out of date) is that in Postscript specifically a hairline is defined as a one device pixel width line. For this reason many printers recommend instead of specifying "Hairline" as the width to choose no less than 0.25 to 0.5 points for line widths, because on high resolution devices a device pixel might be too narrow to reproduce.

Comment: Hairline has been a printing term in use long, long, long, long before "device pixels" was even a thing. In reality, you *can't* create a hairline on digital devices since the smallest increment is 1px, which I understand is what you are eluding to. However, a pixel as no physical size, so .5pt has no direct correlation to pixels, even if Adobe arbitrarily decided 1pt = 1px so their software made sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

In printing, rather than in pure typography, which is probably where you will encounter the term most, a hairline refers to the thinnest line that a given printing device can reproduce properly.

That brings a problem - the definition means that the physical width of a printed hairline will vary from device to device according to its resolution.

For example, on a 300 dpi laser printer a hairline would in simple terms be 1/300" (0.085mm / 0.24pt) wide, which is a reasonably visible line, but on an imagesetter with a resolution of 2540 dpi it would be only 1/2540" (0.01mm / 0.028pt) wide, which is barely visible.

So, in general it is better always to specify line width numerically, eg 0.1mm or 0.28pt or more if you want it to be visible and reasonably similar on any printer.

Answer (score 0):

> **hairline**  The thinnest part of a letter other than the serif

Source: *Type Matters!*

Comment: Yes, **if** referring to type. But "hairline" is **not** exclusively a typographic term.

Comment: the typographic definition seems the most relevant given the images and text in the question.

Comment: While that statement *may be* true based upon type size, it's not really an exclusive typographic term. Yes the thinest part of a glyph *may* be a hairline, but it's not *always* a hairline.

Comment: That depends on your definition of hairline.

Comment: Did you notice the typography tag?